# Othello - Algorithm for finding the available options to play

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, user-interface, matrix

I'm trying to develop the game Othello using Java and I'm struggling with the implementation of finding the available moves **the player has**(not computer).

For example I'm player 1, and I'm playing with the white pieces,

1. Check if the button is empty or not. (I'm using buttons as tiles)
2. Check if there're any neighbors of the opposite color.
3. If there is, continue checking every direction there's an opposite color until
4. If we reach a boundary - return false.
5. If we reach our color - turn all the pieces to my color.

I'm struggling implementing 3. and 5.

How can I Iterate through all the directions ( maximum of 8 directions if I'm in the inner part of the board ), and how can I can advance on checking the colors in each direction?

I thought about implementing all the 8 directions for the inner board, and then implementing all the possibilities in the outer board and checking edge options which is VERY not efficient and I don't want to code like that.

You don't have to look on the code, I'm trying to figure out how to approach it (thinking about 2 for loops), but here's the function and the whole code below: (every button has an icon - black/white piece)

```
private void checkLegalPlay(int row, int col) {

        if(playerNum == 0){ //Black player
            if(row > 0 && row < 7 && col > 0 && col < 7){ //Inner board - 
                     //not good, i want from any point of the board
                    for(int i = col-1; i != 0; i--)
                        if(squares[row][i].getIcon() != null){
                            if(squares[row][i].getIcon() == blackPiece){
                                //Advance until boundary - return false
                                //Advance if there're black pieces
                                //If we get to white piece, turn all to 
                                //  white pieces
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

It's already almost 300 lines of code, so I prefer to give a link if you really want to see what I've done so far: -deleted-

Comment: You may create a list of adjacency and another list of booleans to represent the colors in the cells, then iterate through them recursively and adding some conditions to the iteration.

Comment: I'm still confused on how to iterate through the list recursively. @Yahya

Answer (score 0):

Software development is an art of abstraction. You should try to develop a skill to see similarities between pieces of logic and to abstract them away. For example, to check if the move is legal you have to iterate from the cell in different directions applying the same check logic. Moreover, check of a move and applying move (flipping pieces) share the same iteration logic. So let's abstract it away, i.e. let's separate iteration from logic we do inside iteration:

```
    private static final int SIZE = 8;

    static boolean isValidPos(int pos) {
        return pos >= 0 && pos < SIZE;
    }


    static class Point {
        public final int row;
        public final int col;

        public Point(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }
    }


    private static final Point[] ALL_DIRECTIONS = new Point[]{
            new Point(1, 0),
            new Point(1, 1),
            new Point(0, 1),
            new Point(-1, 1),
            new Point(-1, 0),
            new Point(-1, -1),
            new Point(0, -1),
            new Point(1, -1),
    };


    interface CellHandler {
        boolean handleCell(int row, int col, Icon icon);
    }


    void iterateCells(Point start, Point step, CellHandler handler) {
        for (int row = start.row + step.row, col = start.col + step.col;
             isValidPos(row) && isValidPos(col);
             row += step.row, col += step.col) {
            Icon icon = squares[row][col].getIcon();
            // empty cell
            if (icon == null)
                break;
            // handler can stop iteration
            if (!handler.handleCell(row, col, icon))
                break;

        }
    }


    static class CheckCellHandler implements CellHandler {
        private final Icon otherIcon;
        private boolean hasOtherPieces = false;
        private boolean endsWithMine = false;

        public CheckCellHandler(Icon otherIcon) {
            this.otherIcon = otherIcon;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleCell(int row, int column, Icon icon) {
            if (icon == otherIcon) {
                hasOtherPieces = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                endsWithMine = true;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean isGoodMove() {
            return hasOtherPieces && endsWithMine;
        }
    }

    class FlipCellHandler implements CellHandler {
        private final Icon myIcon;
        private final Icon otherIcon;
        private final List<Point> currentFlipList = new ArrayList<Point>();

        public FlipCellHandler(Icon myIcon, Icon otherIcon) {
            this.myIcon = myIcon;
            this.otherIcon = otherIcon;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleCell(int row, int column, Icon icon) {
            if (icon == myIcon) {
                // flip all cells
                for (Point p : currentFlipList) {
                    squares[p.row][p.col].setIcon(myIcon);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                currentFlipList.add(new Point(row, column));
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean checkLegalPlay(int row, int col) {
        ImageIcon otherIcon = (playerNum == 0) ? whitePiece : blackPiece;
        Point start = new Point(row, col);
        for (Point step : ALL_DIRECTIONS) {
            // handler is stateful so create new for each direction
            CheckCellHandler checkCellHandler = new CheckCellHandler(otherIcon);
            iterateCells(start, step, checkCellHandler);
            if (checkCellHandler.isGoodMove())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

`ALL_DIRECTIONS` represents all 8 directions you can navigate. `iterateCells` method accepts some direction and navigates through it till it hits either empty cell or a border. For each non-empty cell `handleCell` of the passed `CellHandler` is called. So now your `checkLegalPlay` becomes simple: implement `CheckCellHandler` and iterate through all possible directions to see if we can flip in that direction. Implementing actual flip logic is actually very similar: just implement `FlipCellHandler` and use it similarly. Note that you can also abstract "current player" away by explicitly passing `myIcon` and `otherIcon` to handlers.